# Speed up the startup of BroadcastReceiver at reboot

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've an app where the user can call custom lock screen to lock his/her mobile, that is an activity called `LockScreen.class`.
One this screen is loaded, i.e. the deviced is locked, a `SharedPreferences` called  `IsLocked` is assigned to be true.
once the user do what he need with tthe lock screen this `islocked` became false, and the mobile is back to normal.

Every hing is working fine as expected.

The problem is, if for some reason the mobile had been rebooted while the `lock` screen is active, it is not running back upon a reboot.

So, I created a `BootReciever` as below, this works fine BUT after having the reboot process completed, and the user can do many things before it is loaded, my question is `how can I make it loaded faster?` so that the mobile screen is locked again with the custom activity before giving the chance for the user to do anything with the mobile?

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    final String IsLockedPref = "IsLocked";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Boolean islocked = mPrefs.getBoolean(IsLockedPref, false);

        Intent i;
        if (islocked)
            i = new Intent(context, LockScreen.class);
        else
            i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

part of the manifiest file is:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReciever"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to get use of [this](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/01/tutorial-71-implement-lock-screen-in-android/) by granting `Device Admin` by adding the below, but nothing improved:

In the main Activity:

```
    private static final int ADMIN_INTENT = 15;
    private static final String description = "Some Description About Your Admin";
    private DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager;
    private ComponentName mComponentName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(
                this.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        mComponentName = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mComponentName);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,description);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADMIN_INTENT);
.
.
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == ADMIN_INTENT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered As Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to register as Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

and created empty receiver to extend the DeviceAdminReceiver as:

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

}
```

and added the below to the manifiest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="AdminReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/admin"/>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do from your side is to set a priority to your `intent-filter`. From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority)

> It controls the order in which broadcast receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with higher priority values are called before those with lower values.

```
<intent-filter 
    android:priority="100">
        ...
</intent-filter>
```

> The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 100 was not fast enough in my case, so I used 999, it is accepted for me now.